# How can I create such structure. I am quite a newbie to Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]

Clicking on the plus button should open a dialogue box and takes the user input and wraps the value inside the box.

I saw this on a website, found this very interesting and would like top implement something similar.

Comment: dialogue box / javascript prompt?

Comment: I already have mentioned sir that I need to create modal dialog boxes. How am I supposed to create such tree structure. Please don't down vote without reading the question or understanding it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use d3.js, which is by the way, awesome.

You can try building on top of this example. http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: I tried with this but it requires json data. What I am trying to achieve is connecting elements on a web page.

Comment: Check out this on how to add HTML to D3 nodes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827589/d3-appending-html-to-nodes